# passing multiple parameter in an onclick event

Tags: java, php, onclick, whitespace

I am having an issue passing multiple variables.   Since I am building my table on the fly I am using double quotes to store the HTML.  This seems to be causing an issue on how to build the click event.  While I can get this to function to some degree some of the values being passed have spaces since the column is a note or description that has white spaces. I have tried everything I can think of.

```
$sql="SELECT date, type, description, note, nextdue, alert, id FROM medical 
         where dogid=$id";
     $healthDetails = "<table border='1'>";
     $healthDetails .= "<tr>";
     $healthDetails .= "<td>Date</td>";
     $healthDetails .= "<td>Type</td>";
     $healthDetails .= "<td>Description</td>";
     $healthDetails .= "<td>Note</td>";
     $healthDetails .= "<td>Next Due</td>";
     $healthDetails .= "<td>Alert</td>";
     $healthDetails .= '<td>Action</td>';
           foreach( $db->query($sql) as $data ) {
         $healthDetails .= "<tr>";
         $healthDetails .= "<td> $data[0] </td><td> $data[1] </td><td> $data[2] </td><td> $data[3] </td><td> $data[4] </td><td> $data[5] </td>";
         $healthDetails .= "<td><a href=# onClick=editHealth('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[6]'); > Edit</a> | <a href=''>Delete </a></td>";
         $healthDetails .= "</tr>";             }
         $healthDetails .= "</table>";
   echo $healthDetails;
```

I have tried and had luck with \".  This allows me to pass white spaces but will only let me pass one value "

```
 $healthDetails .= "<td><a href=# onClick='editHealth(\"$data[0]\",\"$data[1]\")'> Edit</a> | <a href=#>Delete </a></td>";
```

I have tried this as well but white spaces wont pass.

```
 $healthDetails .= <td><a href=# onClick='editHealth(\''$data[0]'\',\''$data[1]'\')'> Edit</a> | <a href=#>Delete </a></td>
```

Guessing that the entire issue is that I can't double quote the "" the onClick event

```
 $healthDetails .= <td><a href=# onClick="editHealth(\''$data[0]'\',\''$data[1]'\')"> Edit</a> | <a href=#>Delete </a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method and moved to JSON.